How to zip folders with subfolders containing .yml files using Python
I have a folder "a" which has subfolders "b" with subfolders "c" that contain .yml files. I want to zip all the .yml files in the subfolders "b" or "c" without the nested folder structure, so the .zip would contain all the .yml files. Below is the Python code I have so far. It is not zipping all the .yml files within the subfolders.
import os
from zipfile import ZipFile

# # Adding files that need to be zipped
directory_to_zip = r'filepath'

# Create a ZipFile Object
with ZipFile(r'filepath\helper.zip', 'w') as zip_object:
    # Traverse the directory and add YAML files to the zip
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory_to_zip):
        for file in files:
            if file.endswith('.yml'):
                # Create the complete filepath
                file_path = os.path.join(root, file)
                # Write the file to the zip file with just the filename, ignoring directories
                zip_object.write(file_path, file)

# Check to see if the zip file is created
if os.path.exists(r'filepath\helper.zip'):
    print("ZIP file created")
else:
    print("ZIP file not created")


Could you please elaborate on which specific files are not being added to the zip file? Is there a particular pattern among the files that are being missed?

You need to explain in the question exactly what you mean by "It is not zipping all the .yml files within the subfolders.", with an example. Your script works just fine as far as I can tell.

@MarkAdler What I meant when I say "it is not zipping all the .yml files" is under the main folder "a" there are multiple unique subfolders and under the subfolder there are again unique subfolder with unique .yml files. So, the .py code I have is not bringing all the .yml files from al the subfolders into .zip file.

It works for me, no matter how deep the .yml files appear. Give an explicit example of it not working in the question. That means showing the exact set of directory names and file names, identifying which files are being zipped, and which are not. (Not in comments — edit the question.)

@MarkAdler I'm not yet able to edit my question for some reason it is not allowing me to.

When you add files to the zip archive using zip_object.write(file_path, file) it stores the files directly into the root of the zip archive. If multiple files have the same name config.yml in different subfolders they will overwrite each other.
# Path to the directory you want to zip
directory_to_zip = r'filepath\a'

# Path where you want to save the zip file
zip_file_path = r'filepath\helper.zip'

# Create a ZipFile Object
with ZipFile(zip_file_path, 'w') as zip_object:
    # Traverse the directory and add YAML files to the zip
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory_to_zip):
        for file in files:
            if file.endswith('.yml'):
                # Create the complete filepath
                file_path = os.path.join(root, file)
                
                # Option 1: If you want to keep the filenames unique by adding the parent directory's name
                archive_name = os.path.join(os.path.basename(root), file)
                
                # Option 2: If you're okay with just the filenames and are sure there are no conflicts
                # archive_name = file

                # Write the file to the zip file with the adjusted filename
                zip_object.write(file_path, archive_name)

# Check to see if the zip file is created
if os.path.exists(zip_file_path):
    print("ZIP file created")
else:
    print("ZIP file not created")

This should stop potential conflicts in file names including parent directory name. The code should also ensure that your .yml files are included in zip file without nesting them.
EDIT: There has been some incorrect information posted on this answer. The correct information has been outlined by Mark Adler who clarified that "You are incorrect. Files with exactly the same name can be added to the zip file. Python will issue a warning, but will proceed to add the file anyway".

I want to use the above 2nd option, but it is only zipping some .yml files but not all. I guess its because of the folder structure I have, the folder structure is nested so basically its like a->subfolder1->subfolder1.1->.yml , a->subfolder2->subfolder.2.1->.yml and so on.....

can you reset your environment and retry?

Zip files, to the best of my knowledge, can contain files with identical names because they are tracked by index or a similar mechanism, rather than by file name. Therefore, I am uncertain if this is the issue. Additionally, I tested the original script, and it functioned correctly for me, even with .yml files having the same name in different directories.

Indeed, this is true provided they are stored in different directories within the archive. The issue was for files overwriting each other if you explicitly specify the same name in the zip archive for multiple files regardless of their directory structure.

@lvand You are incorrect. Files with exactly the same name can be added to the zip file. Python will issue a warning, but will proceed to add the file anyway.

@Ivand your code worked fine, my bad I just realised there are few files with .yaml and few other with .yml

My apologies @Mark Adler, I'll edit my answer to this when I'm home.
